# How to update value in one controller if the value is updated in different controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a page design in which i have attached the main controller to body:

```
<body ng-controller="firstController">
    <a href="#">first</a>
    <a href="#/second">second</a>
    <input ng-model="hello" ng-disabled="xyz()">
    <button id="test" ng-disabled="xyz()">test button</button>
    {{hello}}
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

I load a template for default as

```
 var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/first.html',
            controller: 'firstTemplate'
    })
```

I my template i a check box as:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check">
</div>
```

Now i want the button #id to be disable the check box is unchecked, now i thought of using factory as these two are in different controllers:

```
mainApp.factory('clientId',function(){
    var flag = true;
    return flag;
});

mainApp.controller('firstController',['$scope','clientId',function($scope,clientId){
    //$scope.check = true;
    clientId.flag = false;
    $scope.xyz = function(){
        if(clientId){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}])
```

I am able to get the value from factory, now i want to update the value of the flag from different controller(template controller) and the value should reflect in first controller too so that the state of button can be updated.

```
 mainApp.controller('firstTemplate',['$scope','clientId',function($scope,clientId){
}])
```

How can i update the value from second controller and make it reflect in first controller. If it is not possible is there and alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can solve this using two ways.
  1. using $rootScope.
  2. using services.
```

using $rootScope:

```
  <input ng-model="hello" ng-disabled="flagtoDisable">
        <button id="test" ng-disabled="flagtoDisable">test button</button>
        {{hello}}
        <div ng-view></div>

mainApp.controller('firstController',    ['$scope','$rootScope','clientId',function($scope,$rootScope,clientId){
    //$scope.check = true;
    clientId.flag = false;
    $scope.xyz = function(){
        if(clientId){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}])



  mainApp.controller('firstTemplate','$scope','$rootScope','clientId',
    function($scope,$rootScope,clientId){
           $rootScope.flagtoDisable = false;
    if($scope.check == true){
             $rootScope.flagtoDisable = true;
      }

    }])
```

using Service:

```
mainApp.factory('clientId',function(){
    var flag = {
               status:false; };
    return{
      setFlag : funcion() {
           flag.status = true;  
          }  
      getFlag : funcion() {
           return flag;  
          }  

});

mainApp.controller('firstController',['$scope','clientId',function($scope,clientId){
    //$scope.check = true;

    $scope.xyz = function(){
        var flag = clientId.getFlag();
       return flag.status;    
    }
}])

<input ng-model="hello" ng-disabled="xyz()">
    <button id="test" ng-disabled="xyz()">test button</button>
    {{hello}}
    <div ng-view></div>

 mainApp.controller('firstTemplate',['$scope','clientId',function($scope,clientId){
if($scope.check== true){
clientId.setFlag();
}
}])
```

This code is not tested.you can follow this approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do it by using [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

The ways are.

- Initialize the   `$rootScope` in your controller
- Call the first controller scope variable from second controller

if 1st controller varaiable is `$scope.name`

now you just call `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` in second controller

like

```
$rootScope.name
```

Comment: how should i update value in rootscope variable for example i am using `$rootScope.toCheck = $scope.checked;`  but only the initial value is assigned when i check and uncheck the box  the value is not reflected in other controller.

Comment: I am using `if($rootScope.toCheck){
   return true;
  }else{
   return false;
  }` in other controller